# I Want to populate the Expandable Listview from the data stored in the sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, expandablelistview, simplecursortreeadapter

I want to populate the Expandable Listview from the data stored in the sqlite database.

my Table is

```
id int pk
name varchar
mobile varchare
age int
```

and I want to display name and when I click on that name it will show the mobile and age in expand list.

I did not get any idea, about it.
If you have any solution then please help. 
And all answers of previous questions like this were not useful.
So I am asking this question again.

I did not understand actually how to do this.

Comment: See this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/)
make header list of name
and child as sub data you want to show after click

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I already tried this link ,that was helpful, but there statically list items are added and I want to add from sqlite database.

Comment: I have referred following link for reference..  http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/   now I want it to be done with the SQlite

Answer (score 0):

HashMap is solution for this. You have to create ArrayList with Generic class (name, age).

For Example :

```
HashMap<ArraList<Integer>,ArrayList<Generic class name>
```

Comment: Sure, but I want it to be fill up with item retrieved from the SQLITE database.